# What is the cause of error by using NSPredictate?

Tags: objective-c

I used the NSPredictate Class, but the following error has occurred.
I Can't know the reason.

Why does occur following error?

[image]

Follow is source code.

```
#import "Predictate.h"

@implementation Predictate

@synthesize dictate;

-(id)init{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)Predictate{
    dictate = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"AAA",@"BBB",@"CCC", nil];
    NSPredicate *test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dictate like 'AAA'"];

    NSMutableArray *result = [dictate filteredArrayUsingPredicate:test];

    NSLog(@"%@",result);
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [dictate release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Error message is below.

2012-01-02 00:57:39.972 filter[1750:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFConstantString 0x100002290> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key dictate.'

Comment: Making a screenshot of your code (plus error) and posting it here is not really the format we prefer. Consider copy/pasting the code and the error to StackOverflow.

Comment: Please replace the screenshot with the actual code that can be copy-pasted into XCode and tried out locally.

Comment: What's the error?  I lost my mind reading skills a few years ago.

Comment: haha, I suspect people are voting down because they are used to looking at text rather than screenshots, good use of the little known shift-command 4 then hit spacebar though..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `NSPredicate` to filter an array of string objects, but are using `dictate like 'AAA'`. The predicate will have absolutely no idea what this `dictate` means.

You will want to replace `dictate` with `SELF`, so that it becomes `"SELF like 'AAA'"`

Comment: you beat me (you have bested my spaniard, which means you must have studied)